# extractText() function in pyPDF2 throws error

Tags: python, pdf, python-3.x, pypdf

I am trying to extract text from PDFs so that I can analyze it but when I try to extract the text from a page I receive the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\eclipse\plugins\org.python.pydev_2.7.4.2013051601\pysrc\pydevd_comm.py", line 765, in doIt
    result = pydevd_vars.evaluateExpression(self.thread_id, self.frame_id, self.expression, self.doExec)

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\eclipse\plugins\org.python.pydev_2.7.4.2013051601\pysrc\pydevd_vars.py", line 376, in evaluateExpression
    result = eval(compiled, updated_globals, frame.f_locals)

File "<string>", line 1, in <module>

File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\pypdf2-1.9.0-py3.3.egg\PyPDF2\pdf.py", line 1701, in extractText
    content = ContentStream(content, self.pdf)

File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\pypdf2-1.9.0-py3.3.egg\PyPDF2\pdf.py", line 1783, in __init__
    stream = StringIO(stream.getData())

File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\pypdf2-1.9.0-py3.3.egg\PyPDF2\generic.py", line 801, in getData
    decoded._data = filters.decodeStreamData(self)

File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\pypdf2-1.9.0-py3.3.egg\PyPDF2\filters.py", line 228, in decodeStreamData
    data = ASCII85Decode.decode(data)

File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\pypdf2-1.9.0-py3.3.egg\PyPDF2\filters.py", line 170, in decode
    data = [y for y in data if not (y in ' \n\r\t')]

File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\pypdf2-1.9.0-py3.3.egg\PyPDF2\filters.py", line 170, in <listcomp>
    data = [y for y in data if not (y in ' \n\r\t')]

TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not int
```

The relevant code sections follow:

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader

for PDF_Entry in self.PDF_List:
    Pdf_File = PdfFileReader(open(PDF_Entry, "rb"))
    for pg_idx in range(0, Pdf_File.getNumPages()):
        page_Content = Pdf_File.getPage(pg_idx).extractText()
        for line in page_Content.split("\n"):
            self.Analyse_Line(line)
```

The error is thrown at the extractText() line.

Answer (score 2):

It may be worth trying the latest version of PyPDF2, latest as I write this is 1.24.

With that said, I have found the extractText() feature to be very fragile.  It works on some documents, fails on others.  See some open issues:

https://github.com/mstamy2/PyPDF2/issues/180 and https://github.com/mstamy2/PyPDF2/issues/168

I worked around the problem by using the Poppler command-line utility pdftotext instead, both to classify a doc as image vs text and to get all the content.  Has been extremely stable for me - I've run it on thousands of PDF documents.  In my experience it also extracts text without further ado from protected/encrypted PDFs.

For example (written for Python 2):

```
def consult_pdftotext(filename):
    '''
    Runs pdftotext to extract text of pages 1..3.
    Returns the count of characters received.

    `filename`: Name of PDF file to be analyzed.
    '''
    print("Running pdftotext on file %s" % filename, file=sys.stderr)
    # don't forget that final hyphen to say, write to stdout!!
    cmd_args = [ "pdftotext", "-f", "1", "-l", "3", filename, "-" ]
    pdf_pipe = subprocess.Popen(cmd_args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    std_out, std_err = pdf_pipe.communicate()
    count = len(std_out)
    return count
```

HTH

Answer (score 1):

You are doing two things in one line. Try to break things done to get closer to the problem. Change:

```
page_Content = Pdf_File.getPage(pg_idx).extractText()
```

into

```
page = Pdf_File.getPage(pg_idx)
page_Content = page.extractText()
```

To see where the error happens. Also run the program from the command line not from Eclipse just to make sure it is the same error. You say it happens at `extractText()` but this line does not show up in the traceback.

Comment: I tested it in the console broken as you suggested and getPage worked fine. extractText() however threw the same error as before.

Comment: I see invocation of extractText at line 4 (counting down from the top) in the posted traceback.